# WPF Drawing context

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, brush, pen

In my wpf application i am drawing a lot of geometries as below. My requirement is to change the color of drawingvisual with out redrawing it? any possibilities in wpf?

```
  using (DrawingContext vDrawingContext = vDrawingVisual.RenderOpen())
        {
          StreamGeometry vGeom = GetCutGeometry(mLength, mWidth);
          vDrawingContext.DrawGeometry(mBackGroundBrush, ForeGroundPen, vGeom);
          vDrawingContext.Close();
          VisualChildren.Add(vDrawingVisual);    

        }
```

How could be mBackGroundBrush dyamic colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that `mBackGroundBrush` is a modifiable `SolidColorBrush` (i.e. it is created in your application and none of the predefined brushes), you could simply change its `Color` property. That will change the fill color of each drawn geometry with redrawing.

```
private SolidColorBrush mBackGroundBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

...

mBackGroundBrush.Color = Colors.Red;
```

or

```
mBackGroundBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Well, it works perfectly for me. Maybe you post a little bit more code like the declaration of `mBackGroundBrush` and where you change it.

Comment: Brush mBackGroundBrush = null;

Comment: A Big thanks, I was changing the Brush instance as  mBackGroundBrush  = new SolidColorBrush(..) that was my mistake....

Comment: Clemens, how do you completely "erase" an object that has already been drawn?  The `DrawingContext` class only has "draw" methods, nothing else (except a Dispose() method that wipes everything out).

Comment: @Sabuncu The Dispose method just closes the DrawingContext, but does not "wipe out" anything. In order to remove a certain object from a DrawingVisual, you will usually have to do a complete redraw.

Comment: How do I do a "complete" redraw?  Do you mean, for example, deleting the GlyphRun object I have created, then building it again and calling DrawGlyphRun()?  What I am missing is this: there's some drawing in the DC.  How can I get rid of some portion of it - for example, get rid of only the last GlyphRun I have drawn? PS: Should I post a question for this so that you can get credit?  Will be happy to.

Comment: You should indeed post a question. How else should anybody know what there is in your DrawGlyphRun method? But in short, when you call RenderOpen on a DrawingVisual, you already start a complete redraw. There will be nothing "left over" from any previous drawing.

Comment: Thanks.  My code currently does not use RenderOpen, so I will look into it.  I only have OnRender in which I call DrawGlyphRun.

Answer (score 1):

I have done one work around as below. seems working.

```
///Kept as arefrence while initial drawing phase.
private DrawingVisual mDrawingVisual = null;

 if (null != mDrawingVisual)
      {
        using (DrawingContext vDrawingContext = mDrawingVisual.RenderOpen())
        {
          DrawingGroup vDrawingGroup = VisualTreeHelper.GetDrawing(mDrawingVisual);
          if (null != vDrawingGroup)
          {
            foreach (Drawing vDrawing in vDrawingGroup.Children)
            {
              GeometryDrawing vGeometryDrawing = vDrawing as GeometryDrawing;
              if (null != vGeometryDrawing)
              {
                vGeometryDrawing.Brush = mBackGroundBrush;
              }
            }
          }

          vDrawingContext.DrawDrawing(vDrawingGroup);
          vDrawingContext.Close();
        }
      }
```

Comment: mBackGroundBrush is updated when i need colour change , and called above code for color changes

Comment: That's not necessary, just change the Color property of the brush.

Comment: It is not working because the element drawn in drawing context remains stable unless it is redrawn again.

Comment: Whatever "remains stable" means, I can create a DrawingVisual with a filled geometry and render it *exactly once*. When I later change the Color of the fill brush, the drawn geometry changes its color on screen, *without redrawing*. If that doesn't work for you, you are certainly doing something else wrong.

Comment: I trust you. Surely i will dig my code and  find what is went wrong and let you know

Comment: A Big thanks, I was changing the Brush instance as  mBackGroundBrush  = new SolidColorBrush(..) that was my mistake....